# Stop views autorefresh from updating the list automatically

Tags: 7, views

[Views autorefresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) allows to refresh automatically and update a view. It is working perfectly, but I want to stop it from updating the views automatically.

When there is a new item in the list, it should show a link "Click to view new item". When the user clicks it, the view should be updated with the new items.

Is it possible using views autorefresh?

Note: The view is not a content type, It is showing the list of [statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses).